# Why are the pygame arrow values not the same as the ascii values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using the pygame library and I went to print out the value as follows:

```
print(pygame.K_UP)
```

and I got 1073741906 as the value. What's the explanation?

```
pygame.K_a
```

is 97 as expected. It's also possible that this is simply a Python thing and not pygame specific.

Comment: What ascii value were you expecting? There isn't an ascii value for the up key.

Comment: Hmmm...after looking it up, you're right. Where is that value coming from then?

Comment: I think it comes from SDL, but beyond that it could be completely arbitrary as far as I know. Presumably chosen not to clash with anything else.

Comment: 1073741906 is 40000052 hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of the [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module:

> Portability note: The integers for key constants differ between pygame 1 and 2. Always use key constants (K_a) rather than integers directly (97) so that your key handling code works well on both pygame 1 and pygame 2.